# 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'get', Request.args.get

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, get, httprequest

I'm coding a little Flask app in Python 3.4, but I've run into a problem with parsing GET requests. Request.args is a 'cached_object', not a function or MultiDict like in other examples, giving for example the error shown in the title. Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, Request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def FooBar():
    return Request.args.get("foobar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=80, host='0.0.0.0')
```

What's the issue here? This is running on Debian 8.1 with the latest version of Flask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `request`, not `Request`.

```
from flask import request

...

request.args.get(...)
```

Comment: Wierd, request with lowercase didn't work last time. Works now though, thanks!